# PayPal's Express Checkout Sandbox after payment hangs on confirmation

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate the **PAYPAL Express Checkout** which the **PHP API**. All the code is fine as per the documentation provided by the Paypal. I have added the merchant email and also all the parameter are correct.

But then i use to test, a popup is opened and sandbox account logged in successfully. The item detail is shown over there and after that clicking on the pay now button, the popup is closed and I am left at this page :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow?execution=e1s2

and never returns to the merchant site. And below is the controller code which sends user to paypal :

```
    /**
     * Purchase the item and then redirect to the paypal page
     * @param type $id
     */
    public function purchase($id = '') {
        //Loading the required helpers and the libraries which is to be used in this function
        $this->load->helper('paypal');
        //Get all the item fields from the database
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $item_fields = itemsfieldsquery::create()->filterByitemid($id)->find();
        //Fetch the requested item form the database with its detail 
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $item = itemsquery::create()->filterByid($id)->findOne();

        //Fetch the item author detail from the database
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $user_detail = userprofilequery::create()->filterByid(useritemsquery::create()->filterByitemid($id)->findOne()->getuserid())->findOne();
        //set the array wit the kay 
        foreach ($item_fields as $fields) {
            $data[categoriesfieldquery::create()->filterByid($fields->getfieldid())->findOne()->getfieldtype()] = $fields->getfieldvalue();
        }

        // ==================================
        // PayPal Express Checkout Module
        // ==================================
        //'------------------------------------
        //' The paymentAmount is the total value of
        //' the purchase.
        //'
        //' TODO: Enter the total Payment Amount within the quotes.
        //' example : $paymentAmount = "15.00";
        //'------------------------------------
        $paymentAmount = $data['item_price'];

        //'------------------------------------
        //' The currencyCodeType
        //' is set to the selections made on the Integration Assistant
        //'------------------------------------
        $currencyCodeType = "USD";
        $paymentType = "Sale";

        //'------------------------------------
        //' The returnURL is the location where buyers return to when a
        //' payment has been succesfully authorized.
        //'
        //' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant
        //'------------------------------------
        $returnURL = site_url('item/transaction');

        //'------------------------------------
        //' The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
        //' cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow
        //'
        //' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant
        //'------------------------------------
        $cancelURL = site_url('item/transaction');

        //'------------------------------------
        //' Calls the SetExpressCheckout API call
        //'
        //' The CallSetExpressCheckout function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
        //' it is included at the top of this file.
        //'-------------------------------------------------

        $items = array();
        $items[] = array('name' => $item->getitemname(), 'amt' => $paymentAmount, 'qty' => 1, 'custom' => $id);

        //::ITEMS::
        // to add anothe item, uncomment the lines below and comment the line above
        // $items[] = array('name' => 'Item Name1', 'amt' => $itemAmount1, 'qty' => 1);
        // $items[] = array('name' => 'Item Name2', 'amt' => $itemAmount2, 'qty' => 1);
        // $paymentAmount = $itemAmount1 + $itemAmount2;
        // assign corresponding item amounts to "$itemAmount1" and "$itemAmount2"
        // NOTE : sum of all the item amounts should be equal to payment amount

        $resArray = SetExpressCheckoutDG($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $items);

        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
        if ($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            //Redirect user to the paypal 
            RedirectToPayPalDG($token);
        } else {
            //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the 
            //following error information returned by PayPal
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
            $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
            $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
            $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

            $data['error'] = "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
            $data['error'] .= "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
            $data['error'] .= "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
            $data['error'] .= "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
            $data['error'] .= "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
            //Paint the page if we got the error
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            $this->stencil->paint('item/thanks', $data);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve this error or have any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code? It's hard to help you, when we don't know, how your scripts working.

Comment: Yes sure, i have added the code and please review the code.

Comment: Can you include a var_dump of $res_array? Exclude any personal details like name/API credentials.

Comment: @TMP I didn't found solution yet. Actually I have hold this task for right now.

Comment: Yeah me neither, still have the problem using ActiveMerchant with Paypal in Ruby. Have talked to Paypal support a few times for multiple hours and they're no help

Comment: @AjayKumar I have found that it happens when I'm using the same IP for my buyer and seller. When I was talking to paypal they reset the IP's on the accounts and then the next attempt worked! Followed by more failures

Comment: @TMP I will also try using this option and let you know asap.